# Drawing a single pixel or line at a time in WPF and SHOW it

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm migrating my ray tracer to C# and WPF, but I'm having trouble with the simplest of things: How to display each pixel (or line) on a canvas or bitmap.

I want to be able to see every new pixel (or at least every finished line) when they're done, and not wait until the whole image has been created.

Like many RayTracers, I have a central loop-in-a-loop, which 'scans' the screen:

```
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        pixelRGB = SendRay(...);

        // PLEASE help me update the image here ! :-)
        DrawPixelAndLetTheUserSeeIt();
    }
}
```

I've tried using WritableBitmap or writing directly to the canvas but regardles,
the image isn't updated/shown, until the entire loop has finished.

I suspect is has something to do with threads, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: This is not how WPF works. There's no such thing as a "central loop" or anything like that. Start reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: if you figure this out, please post an answer.... I've been looking all day for this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar at all with WPF, so please excuse me if i'm off-topic.
May there be some *double-buffer* here that prevents you to control when the graphical update is effectively done ?

If so you may want to trigger yourself the *swaping of the buffer* to graphics surface.

Comment: Thanks, but no. Thats not it at all. If, for instance, I call a MessageBox.Show("!!"); when its half way through, the part of the image that was already rendered is shown. So, it _must_ be some queing mechanism that doesn't allow the image to be updated.